# I need a query to create a week circle

Tags: postgresql, sql-date-functions

I already write this query

```
    Select to_date(concat(to_char(kyc.kyc_verify_date,'YY-MM'),'-01'),'YY-MM-DD') AS "Month"
    Count (columnname)
    From kyc;
```

And the table result i given like this:

```
         Month                count

January 1, 2021, 12:00 AM     2324

February 1, 2021, 12:00 AM    23245
```

As you can see, the date always start from the 1st day of the month.

**Now i need a query for a week, just like that query, it will start from Monday
Can someone help me with this.**

Thank you

Comment: `to_date(concat(to_char(kyc.kyc_verify_date,'YY-MM'),'-01'),'YY-MM-DD')` can be simplified to `date_trunc('month', kyc.kyc_verify_date)::date`

Comment: tks you, i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `date_trunc` function, it does exactly what you need (and it will also do the trick for months, so you can simplify your original example):

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', current_timestamp);

       date_trunc       
════════════════════════
 2022-02-07 00:00:00+01
(1 row)
```